# Reading from a txt file in assembly MASM?

Tags: file, assembly, text, masm, irvine32

In the code below, `buffer` is my buffer read, `fileName` is the name of the file, `bytesRead` is supposed to be the returned string.

I try to read from it, but it tells me that the buffer size is 6.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE macros.inc

.data
MAX = 5000
fileName BYTE 80 DUP (?)
fileHandle HANDLE ?
bytesRead DWORD ?
buffer BYTE MAX DUP(?)

.code
main PROC

mov  EDX,OFFSET fileName
call ReadString

mov  EDX,OFFSET fileName
call OpenInputFile
mov  fileHandle, EAX

mov  eax,fileHandle
mov  ecx,MAX
call ReadFromFile
mov  bytesRead,eax
mov  edx, offset bytesRead
call WriteString
call crlf
call WriteDec
call crlf

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 1):

RTFM:

ReadFromFile PROC

Reads an input file into a buffer.

Call args:

- EAX = an open file handle
- EDX = offset of the input buffer
- ECX = maximum number of bytes to read

Return arg: 
If CF = 0, EAX contains the number of bytes read. 
If CF = 1, EAX contains a system error code. Call WriteWindowsMsg 
to get a text representation of the error.

Example:

```
.data
BUFSIZE = 5000
buffer BYTE BUFSIZE DUP(?)
bytesRead DWORD ?

.code
  mov  eax,fileHandle
  mov  edx,OFFSET buffer
  mov  ecx,BUFSIZE
  call ReadFromFile
  jc   show_error_message
  mov  bytesRead,eax
```

You need `OFFSET buffer` in there. `bytesRead` is the number of bytes read, not a string, your text should be in `buffer`.